# Disable parameters based on selection in Crystal Reports

Tags: stored-procedures, crystal-reports, reporting

I am using Crystal reports to generate a report using a particular date parameter, either the range between `@p_start_date` and `@p_end_date` or `@t_start_date` and `@t_end_date` can be used. An IF statement in the stored proc determines which date to use via a boolean param specified by the user at report runtime (`@use_p_date`).

What I want to do is if `@use_p_date` is 1 then disable the other date fields (`@t_start_date` and `@t_end_date`) for selection since they will not be used, and vice vera if `@use_p_date` is set to false.

Can this be done? If yes then how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this can be done. I'm sure there are different ways to go about it, but a pretty simple one would be:

```
    BEGIN
IF (@use_p_date) =1 
    SELECT * FROM DataBase
    WHERE OrderDate >=@p_start_date and OrderDate =< @p_end_date
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM DataBase
    WHERE OrderDate >=@t_start_date and OrderDate =< @t_end_date

END
```

Database is obviously your database, OrderDate is the data field your date parameters are looking at.

EDIT:

To do this in CR itself, you can do two things. You can use a simmilar approach as above by using something like this in your Record Select:

```
If ({?use_p_date} =1 
Then OrderDate >={?p_start_date} and OrderDate =< {?p_end_date}
Else OrderDate >={?t_start_date} and OrderDate =< {?t_end_date}
```

Or you could make your parameters optional and then do something like this in Record Select:

```
if hasvalue({?p_start_date}) and hasValue({?p_end_date}) then .....
else .......
```

Comment: I was more looking for disabled parameters in the actual crystal reports interface not in the Sql itself, this is already in place

Comment: Please see revised answer. The syntax may not be 100% correct, but I hope you get the idea.